# Image in appbar Flutter between Title and Leading

Tags: image, flutter, appbar

Hy! Is that possible to put and Image into an appbar beetween the leading and Title? Or just put an image on the left and right side of Title?

Answer (score 0):

I have somehow made it work in this way :

```
appBar: AppBar(

        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            Icon(Icons.access_alarm)
          ],
        )
      ),
```

you can change it using you images.